# flycheck-gfortran-language-standard option

Tags: flycheck

I have added the following option in my `~/.emacs` file so that it uses the Fortran 2008 standard when checking syntax using Flycheck (as suggested in http://www.flycheck.org/en/latest/_downloads/flycheck.html#Fortran):

```
(flycheck-gfortran-language-standard 2008)
```

When I load emacs, I get the following error messages:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/home/wadud/.emacs':
Symbol's function definition is void: flycheck-gfortran-language-standard
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You called the symbol as a function, but the error suggests there is no function by that name. See the answer post for how to set it as a variable.

Answer (score 2):

It is `-std=f2008` for gfortran.  Therefore there is a small "f" before "2008":

```
(setq flycheck-gfortran-language-standard "f2008")
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
(setq flycheck-gfortran-language-standard 2008)
```